# Bootstrap : trigger dropdown from toggled button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive layout where the desktop view shows search, logo, login. In the xs/mobile view I would like the search and login to collapse into buttons. I can get this layout working just fine. The issue is that in the desktop view, I have a Search Options link that opens a popover with tabbed search forms. I'd like to still have that once you click the collapsed search button. My issue is that the popover is being created inside the  tag instead of after it.

How can I set it up so that there is one div holding the search options that can be displayed from either the desktop view (search bar, Go button, search options link) as well as the mobile view (just a button with a search icon).

I am not tied to the popover- I just liked the look of it and I am not sure how to deal with the data-toggle as it currently is set to "collapse" and it seems I might need it to be able to also somehow be set to "dropdown."

Hopefully there is an easier/better way to do this!

Comment: It collapses when you click something else?

Comment: Well when the viewport is mobile, search field has collapsed into a button, so clicking the button just shows the search field again. What I want it to show is the advanced search options. I suppose I might just need to use some javascript here. I was hoping to use the same javascript for the link regardless of how you click it...but the way popovers are created, the popover is generated within that <button> tag so it is all skinny.